# Array don't return expected text in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Why the following code do not return me `0 => 'Zero'` for the first line but `0 => 0` ?

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i += 1) {
    if($i == 0) { $array[$i] = 'Zero'; }
    $array[$i] = $i;
}

for ($i = 30; $i <= 100; $i += 5) {    
    $array[$i] = $i;
}

for ($i = 100; $i <= 200; $i += 10) {    
    $array[$i] = $i;
}

return $array;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You set element 0 to Zero and then overwrite it in the next line with 0.

Comment: Ok, so it miss an `else`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set element 0 to Zero and then overwrite it in the next line with 0.

```
if($i == 0) { $array[$i] = 'Zero'; }
$array[$i] = $i;
```

You probably want an else...

```
if($i == 0) { 
    $array[$i] = 'Zero'; }
 else {
    $array[$i] = $i;
 }
```

Comment: You could also use `continue` within the if statement instead of using else.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden You could before the return use `$array[0] = 'Zero';` there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i += 1) 
{
    if($i == 0) 
    { 
        $array[$i] = 'Zero'; 
    }
    $array[$i] = $i;
}
```

should be:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i += 1) 
{
    if($i == 0) 
    { 
        $array[$i] = 'Zero'; 
    }
    else
    {
        $array[$i] = $i;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you -1 the question, just because the other user gave me more information than your answer... Thanks.

Comment: I did not -1 the question.

Comment: Just trying to help.